# keep url encoded after submitting redirect_url to facebook

Tags: facebook, urlencode

I am sending to facebook the following redirect url:

```
$redirect_url = 'http://domain.com/facebook.htm/target='.urlencode('domain.com/some/stuff');
```

Instead of returning

```
http://domain.com/facebook.htm/target=domain.com%2Fsome%2Fstuff
```

it is returning it like this:

```
http://domain.com/facebook.htm/target=domain.com/some/stuff
```

Facebook is not keeping my query var encoded. How can I get it back encoded?

Comment: What do you do with $redirect_url?

Comment: I pass the last visited page so I can redirect the user to the page he/she was viewing before login in with facebook.

Comment: My guess is that you need to urlencode it

Comment: _“Facebook is not keeping my query var encoded”_ – maybe the reason is that you _do not have_ a “query var” in the first place (assuming that is supposed to mean query string/GET parameter) – because the query string would start with a `?`. URL-encoded slashes in the _path_ component of a URL are invalid IIRC – and maybe FB tries to auto-correct that. Whether or not they would be right in doing so, one might argue – because with a `=` in it, it is not a valid path either. I’d suggest you try with a _proper_ query string, `?target=…`, and see if the problem persists. If so, open a bug report.